# How does cross entropy loss get calculated in overconfident neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, cross-entropy

Given formula for categorical formula for cross entropy:

[image]

or binary forumla:

[image]

how is cross entropy calculated in overconfident neural netowrks (especially CNNs where this phenomenon is common), e.g. given the output of 3 classes network is `[0, 0, 1]` and ground truth is `[1, 0, 0]`, how is cross entropy calculated, when `log(0)` is undefined.

Comment: You can force values to be at least some epsilon (very small value) distance from exact 0 or 1: https://github.com/itdxer/neupy/blob/master/neupy/algorithms/gd/objectives.py#L182-L200

Comment: $p$ cannot really be 0 unless in cases of finite precision, no weight regularization and extreme overfitting